# bash command for splitting cell content by delimiter into multiple rows in the cell column

Tags: bash, dataframe

To draw a task. I have dataframe:

```
x   y1;y2;y3    z1;z2;z3
a   b1;b2       c1;c2
```

I need:

```
x   y1  z1
x   y2  z2
x   y3  z3
a   b1  c1
a   b2  c2
```

Column 1 has one instance always. Number of instances in a cell can be from one to many but always equal between column 2,3. Thanks

Comment: I changed delimiter in cells for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should make it:

```
declare -a cols=() # array for individual columns (line fields)
IFS=' ;'           # fields separators

while read -a cols; do
    n=${#cols[@]} # number of fields in current line
    if (( n < 3 || n % 2 != 1 )); then # skip invalid lines
        printf "skipping invalid line: %s\n" "${cols[*]}"
        continue
    fi
    for (( i = 1; i <= n / 2; i += 1 )); do # loop over pairs of fields
        # printf line
        printf "%s %s %s\n" "${cols[0]}" "${cols[i]}" "${cols[n/2+i]}"
    done
done < data.txt
```

Explanations:

- `IFS` is the list of characters used by `read` to split a line in fields. In your case spaces and `;` seem to be the separators.
- `read -a cols` assigns the fields of the read line to the `cols` array, starting at cell 0.

Example of run:

```
$ cat data.txt
x   y1;y2;y3    z1;z2;z3
a   b1;b2       c1;c2
$ ./foo.sh
x y1 z1
x y2 z2
x y3 z3
a b1 c1
a b2 c2
```

Comment: Something goes wrong. I get repeated rows for column 1 but various number of instances for 2 and 3. Could you check description once more, I clarified it.

Comment: I do not understand, sorry. I just copy-pasted my code and your input data, without any change and I got exactly your expected output: 3 rows starting with `x` followed by `y1 z1`, `y2 z2` and `y3 z3`, respectively. Then 2 rows starting with `a` and followed by `b1 c1` and `b2 c2`, respectively. Are you 100% sure you accurately explained what you want?

Comment: I edited my answer to show what my output looks like with your input. Can you check yourself and explain what difference you see with what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F"(\t|;)" '{
    for(i=2;i<=4;i++)
        if($i!="")
            print $1, $i, $(i+3) 
}' file
x y1 z1
x y2 z2
x y3 z3
a b1 c1
a b2 c2
```

**Edit**: Another version:

```
$ awk -F"(\t+|;)" '{               # FS tabs or semicolon      
    for(i=2;i<=int(NF/2)+1;i++)
        print $1,$i,$(i+int(NF/2))
}' file
x y1 z1
x y2 z2
x y3 z3
a b1 c1
a b2 c2
```

Comment: Something goes bad. Instances get mixed and single instances in a row occur after first column (no 3rd column)

Comment: Edited the `FS` as the result of changed sample data in the question. Did it change anything?